# preg_replace, remove from characters to first space

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have strings like:

```
$model = "Sony ST26i Xperia J black smartphone"
```

how i can remove `st*` with `preg_replace` to leave:

```
$model = "Sony Xperia J black smartphone"
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: i tryed to find something information, but doesnt find anything

Comment: What do you mean by `charter`?

Comment: How could you not find anything? Have you read the tutorial at regular-expression.info?

Comment: some sybmol, in this case the is "ST"

Comment: You mean _character_?

Answer (score 3):

```
$model = preg_replace('/ST\S*\s/', '', $model);
```

`\S` matches anything that isn't whitespace, `*` means to match any number of them, and then `\s` matches the space after it.

Comment: I wonder if OP will put more, less or equal amount of effort into his question when he already gets an answer with this quality/effort ?

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
$model = preg_replace('#st(\S+)#ig', '', $model);
```

You can test this regex here : [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/cS4iB2/1)

Comment: No need for `[ ]` around `\S`

Comment: No need for `( )` around it, either.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$model = "Sony ST26i Xperia J black smartphone";
$model = preg_replace('/ST\S+/', '', $model);

echo $model;
//Sony Xperia J black smartphone
```